# PHP Uncaught Error when testing RRD support

Tags: php, pecl, rrdtool

I have this PHP file which Im using to test RRD support:

```
<?php
$result=rrd_fetch( "/ang.rrd", array( "AVERAGE", "--resolution", "60", "--start", "-1d", "--end", "start+1h" ) );

foreach ( $result["data"]["myfield"] as $key => $value )
{
    echo "At timestamp $key, the value for myfield is $value.\n";
}
?>
```

If I browse to the file I get the following:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function rrd_fetch() in /var/www/html/graph.php:2\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/graph.php on line 2
```

and if I try to run the file on the command line I get the following:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: myfield in /var/www/html/graph.php on line 4
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/graph.php on line 4
```

Im not sure why. Could somebody shed some light on why this is happening please?

Comment: you need to echo your function `rrd_fetch()`

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar How would that solve the _"Call to undefined function"_-error?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson its Actually Define the function

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar I'm not following you. Do you mean that echo would define that function? Btw, that function returns an array, so wouldn't that result in a _"Array to string conversion"_ notice? (if the function was defined, that is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lies in your error message:

`Call to undefined function rrd_fetch`

The issue is that the rrd functions are not provided by default. They have to be added by install the rrd pecl package.

Try installing rrd and retrying your code: 
https://pecl.php.net/package/rrd

rrd documentation: http://www.php.net/rrd